# l2tp over ipsec on mac osx 10.13.4

Tags: macos, vpn

I want to find `l2tp over ipsec` in macOS 10.13.4 but only get `l2tp/ipsec`. 
Is `l2tp over ipsec` canceled ?

I tried to select the option and connect VPN. But it is not working and I get the connection log:

```
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : l2tp_get_router_address
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.12.1 from dict 1
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : L2TP connecting to server 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (xx.xx.xx.xx)...
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : IPSec connection started
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Sat Sep 15 13:18:12 2018 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Sat Sep 15 13:18:13 2018 : IPSec phase 2 started
Sat Sep 15 13:18:13 2018 : IPSec phase 2 established
Sat Sep 15 13:18:13 2018 : IPSec connection established
Sat Sep 15 13:18:13 2018 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Sat Sep 15 13:18:14 2018 : L2TP received Auth Challenge AVP - not supported
Sat Sep 15 13:18:14 2018 : L2TP received SCCRP
Sat Sep 15 13:18:14 2018 : L2TP sent SCCCN
Sat Sep 15 13:18:14 2018 : L2TP sent ICRQ`
```

Comment: I have the same issue. My endpoint is a Mikrotik router running an L2TP/ipsec server. I can connect to via my android phone but not from my MackBook. I get the exact same log output as the OP

Comment: Security settings have changed since MacOS 10.13 / iOS 13, which leads to issues while connecting to some ipsec server.

If you manage the server, edit `/etc/ipsec.conf` setting file by changing `sha2-truncbug=no` instead of `yes`, and restart your `ipsec` server.

Answer (score 1):

`l2tp/ipsec` is equivalent to `l2tp over ipsec`. The `/` in technical English is often spoken as the word *over*.

You can find **L2TP over IPSec** in the **Network** System Preference settings:

1. Launch **System Preferences**
2. Select **Network**
3. Select **+**
4. Select *Interface* **VPN**
5. Select *VPN Type* **L2TP over IPSec**

[image: L2TP over IPSec]

Comment: hello, i try to select the option and connect vpn. but it is not work. and i get the connection log

Comment: Please can you edit your question to add the type of server/router/device. The error log suggests a configuration error in your settings.